# Inside for loop: Convert text and int to const char* and pass to function

Tags: c++, mbed

I'm trying to convert some text plus an int to const char* inside a "for loop", and then pass this const char* to a function from a library (HTTPClient - mbed). (The function from the library only accepts const char* as parameters, and it simply adds the const char* values to an array, and later on these values are send using HTTP POST).

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char buf1[16];
    char buf2[16];
    char buf3[16];
    sprintf(buf1,"%d",i);
    sprintf(buf2,"Hello%d",i);
    sprintf(buf3,"World%d",i);
    const char* value1 = buf1;
    const char* value2 = buf2;
    const char* value3 = buf3;
    map.put("id[]", value1);
    map.put("test1[]", value2);
    map.put("test2[]", value3);
}
```

But it seems that the values get overwritten during each loop, so that when the HTTP POST is executed the following values are send:

> 2 Hello2 World2
>
> 2 Hello2 World2
>
> 2 Hello2 World2

Instead of:

> 0 Hello0 World0
>
> 1 Hello1 World1
>
> 2 Hello2 World2

I know this has something to do with the fact that a const char* is a pointer, but i'm not sure how to fix it.

I hope you guys can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Hints: `std::string` , `std::string::c_str` , `std::to_string`. Look them up on http://cppreference.com

Comment: You store a pointer to a local array. This array is gone when the loop iteration ends, so all the pointers in map are invalid right after the loop ends.

Comment: What is the type of `map`? It's hard to answer this question without understanding what that object is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On each iteration of the loop variables `bufN` get created and destroyed, but they happen to be created at the same address on the stack (otherwise loops would exhaust stack space).

It looks like `map.put` doesn't copy the strings but rather stores pointers to the strings, your `bufN` variables, which get overwritten with new values on each iteration, this is why you see the last written values.

Also note that `bufN` variables no longer exist after the loop terminate, so that the pointers stored in `map` become invalid. It just so happens that this memory wasn't overwritten with something else.

A fix would be to allocate space for all buffers, e.g.:

```
constexpr int N = 3;
char bufs[N][3][16];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    snprintf(bufs[i][0], sizeof bufs[i][0], "%d", i);
    snprintf(bufs[i][1], sizeof bufs[i][1], "Hello%d", i);
    snprintf(bufs[i][2], sizeof bufs[i][2], "World%d", i);
    map.put("id[]", bufs[i][0]);
    map.put("test1[]", bufs[i][1]);
    map.put("test2[]", bufs[i][2]);
}
```

You need to make sure that `map` doesn't try to access the strings after `bufs` variable has been destroyed (went out of scope).